# mapping Swift Set of struct objects to kotlin Set of data classes with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

For example, I've got this simple business code in kotlin:

```kotlin
class ProjectItemFacade(
    val projects: Set<ProjectEntity>
) {
    fun sortedProjects(): List<ProjectEntity> {
        return projects.toList().sortedBy { it.name }
    }
}

data class ProjectEntity(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String
)
```

I try to call it from Swift like that:

```swift
struct ProjectItem: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    let description: String
}

    let projects: Set = [
        ProjectItem(name: "Zero Project", description: "test1"),
        ProjectItem(name: "First Project", description: "test2"),
        ProjectItem(name: "Third Project", description: "test3"),
    ]
    
    let sortedProjects = ProjectItemFacade(projects: projects).sortedProjects()
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Set<ProjectItem>' to expected argument type 'Set<ProjectEntity>'

Cannot use instance member 'projects' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

It seems like there is a problem with mapping Swift struct to kotlin data class. How to solve it?

**EDIT**

After renaming the kotlin class to the same as in swift it returns first error like that:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Swift.Set<iosApp.ProjectItem>' to expected argument type 'Swift.Set<shared.ProjectItem>'
```

Comment: The second error aside, why are you giving it `ProjectItem`s when it expects `ProjectEntity`s? Typo?

Comment: Should kotlin class name be exactly the same as Swift struct name?

Comment: You should not create a new Swift struct in the first place. You can use the Kotlin class directly from Swift.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper said in comment, I should use kotlin class in my swift code. I decided to map my array like that:

```swift
import Foundation
import shared

struct ProjectItem: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    let description: String
    
    func toEntity() -> ProjectEntity {
        ProjectEntity(id: id, name: name, description: description)
    }
    
    static func fromEntity(_ entity: ProjectEntity) -> ProjectItem {
        ProjectItem(id: entity.id, name: entity.name, description: entity.description_)
    }

}
```

Note that I use `entity.description_` because it seems like `description` property call the data class `toString()` method.

```swift
    let projects: Set = Set(
        [
            ProjectItem(name: "Zero Project", description: "test1"),
            ProjectItem(name: "First Project", description: "test2"),
            ProjectItem(name: "Third Project", description: "test3"),
        ]
        .map { $0.toEntity() }
    )


    var sortedProjects: Array<ProjectEntity> {
        get {
            return ProjectItemFacade(projects: projects)
                .sortedProjects()
        }
    }
```

Computed `get` solved the second error.